# How can I run a php program on a Mac?

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I have index.php file in my htdocs folder. I have MAMP installed in my machine.I dont know how to run this php file. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: see http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~dgb/courses/pwd/amp.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch MAMP;
2. Open http://localhost:8888 on your favorite browser.